# Localização de XML do Spring em um projeto Maven

Tags: maven, spring-mvc

Dentro de um projeto Maven, onde coloco o arquivo do Spring, o `spring-context.xml`?

Answer (score 0):

Você deve colocar dentro de src/main/resources